# How can I implement exactly this animation in my lazy column in Jetpack Compose Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

Please see this video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hzlSrJcInYj6uEqczZIBQ2ofuzC6w48Y/view?usp=drive_link). I have lazycolumn and list is showing. I want to animate it, I tried below things but it's not even taking effect.

Code:

```
LazyColumn(Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(), contentPadding = paddingValues) {

       
        shopDataList?.forEachIndexed { i, dataItem ->
            item(key = "header_$i") {

                CardWithoutTonalElevation(
                    modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement(
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 600
                        )
                    )
```

So Inside CardWithoutTonalElevation expand-collapse functionality is there. this is one card, like that there are list of card are showing that I want to animate when user land everytime in this screen.

Note: Urge you to donwload the video which is in Google Drive with .mov format because I'm not able to upload directly on stackoverflow. Basically it is a screen recoding of the expected functionality from the designer.